# ListView empty as default, data displaying in the List only when user click on search bar or hot reload

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: This is what I get in the ListView as soon as I get into this screen, however I am expecting to display all the elements in the List.]

[image: As you can see in the second screenshot the elements are only displayed in the ListView only once I click in the Search bar (without typing anything),]

My json response is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 791130665,
        "user_id": 513549601,
        "event_id": 843678542,
        "code": "TKHRDSJ",
        "created": "2018-05-25 09:13:15",
        "void": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 937448493,
        "user_id": 513549601,
        "event_id": 843678542,
        "code": "TKUYJGW",
        "created": "2018-05-25 09:14:07",
        "void": 0
    }
]
```

This is the Json Response that I get when I paste the Url
    Json Response for returnTicketDetails = json.decode(response.body);

Answer (score 0):

Your `_searchResult` is initalized as an empty list, and then you update it in `onSearchTextChanged`. You need to initialize `_searchResult` with something else before the first search happens.

I'm not sure when your `userDetails` list is available, but if it is ready early, a good place to initialize `_searchResult` would be on `initState`.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  onSearchTextChanged('');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried to initialised it in initState, however I get: the argument type Map can’t be assigned to the parameter type Iterable . @Edman

Comment: You need to map the items in `userDetails` to your `_searchResult` list. Kind of like what you're doing in `onSearchTextChanged`. But there you're filtering elements, now you don't want to filter.

Comment: Cold you please show me an example?? Sorry but as you can see I am new into Flutter/Dart, much appreciated!

Comment: Updated the answer. If your implementation of `onSearchTextChanged` is correct, that should work.

Comment: Thank you! But for some reason I still get the same output.
No errors whatsoever, but the List is empty as default.
@Edman

Comment: I can provide you a solution if you post your full JSON response.

Comment: I have also uploaded the full code in a new post, with the output of what I get. Feel free to check it out, as I am explaining in great details what I would like to achieve vs the output of what I get.
Thank you again @Vinoth Kumar

Comment: Just execute the url in any browser then copy and post the result data the browser. Because it's too hard to find the issue without accessing the url.

Comment: Post updated @Vinoth Kumar, let me know if you need more info.
Much appreciated

Comment: It's working perfectly for me with the answer i've posted in your previous question with this json output.

Comment: Please check my new question as I am encountering a new issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600735/data-loading-in-the-listview-only-if-i-click-the-search-bar-or-hot-reload
Thank you @Vinoth Kumar

Comment: I think the issue is the way you are retrieving data from web might not be correct.

Comment: Well might be, however I am getting the data in, only if I hit the hot reload button after the app has been launched.
It would't show any data if I was not retrieving data correctly, right?