# ListView populated only if I click the Search form or hot reload

Tags: dart, flutter

```
class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  List  _searchResult = [];


  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();


  var userDetails  = {};
  List returnTicketDetails;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(

            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

            child: new Padding(

              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Card(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: new TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                    onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                  ),
                  trailing: new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel), onPressed: () {
                    controller.clear();
                    onSearchTextChanged('');
                  },),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(

            child: _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty ?
            new ListView.builder(

               itemCount: _searchResult.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {

                return new Card(

                  child: new Column
                    (mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children:
                    <Widget>[
                    new Row(children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                    width: 80.0,
                    height: 80.0,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(

                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: new NetworkImage(

                    "https:.....")
                )
                )),
                    new Text(" " + userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]["first_name"] +  " " + (userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]["last_name"]),


                ])
                    ])
                );
                },
            )
                : new ListView.builder(
               itemCount: _searchResult.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                                     ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

      onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {

            _searchResult.clear();
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          for (int i = 0; i< returnTicketDetails.length;  i++){
            _searchResult.add(userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]);
          }
          setState(() {});
          return;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i< returnTicketDetails.length;  i++){

          if (userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]["first_name"].toString().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()) || userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]["last_name"].toString().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())
              || returnTicketDetails[i]["code"].toString().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
            _searchResult.add(userDetails[returnTicketDetails[i]["user_id"]]);

          }
        }
        setState(() {});
      }
```

I was wondering why when I go into this screen of my app the ListView is empty even though I am expecting to have few elements in the List. However only once I hit the Search bar field or hot reload button, the data gets loaded and my ListView gets populated with the right data??.
Ideally as default I would like to have the ListView displaying all the data in the List as soon as I come in this screen, and then start to search filter through the element of my List according to user input.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
I guess the problem is with the line
**child: _searchResult.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty ?**

since you don't have anything in the _searchResult when the app loads first time your

**new ListView.builder(
               itemCount: _searchResult.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                                     ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),**

is being rendered with no content to display and when you start typing in the text box onSearchTextChanged is called and the other ListView.builder is rendered with some data (as in your case 2,3 items in list).

Hope it helps!!!
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I actually thought the problem could have been there however I don’t know how to further edit it, do you have any suggestion for the implementation?? Thank you

Comment: Override "void initState ()" which will be called when the widget is rendered for the first time and call your  onSearchTextChanged() inside it.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your response!
I have tried as you said, however whenever I go to the ListView screen I get:
E/flutter ( 3973): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 3973): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 3973): Tried calling: length